# How to searching and extracting substring from text in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have formula in excel and i want use it in SQL Server. What queries i can use?

[image]

formula in Excel:

```
=IFERROR(MID(A2,FIND("=",A2,8)+1,FIND("Logic",A2,8)-4-FIND("=",A2,8)+1),MID(A2,FIND("=",A2,8)+1,5))
```

whats formula in SQL server?

thanks for your attention, and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Your question is not about "formulas" and `IFERROR`. It's about searching and extracting substring from text. If you start thinking about it this way, you may find lots of examples.

Comment: im sorry, i will edit my question, thanks for your correction.

Comment: It's better to search for similar questions first.

Comment: Would be helpful if the actual requirement is explained, many people here aren't familiar with excel formula(s).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Logic',A2, 8) > 0 
    THEN SUBSTRING( A2, CHARINDEX( '=',A2, 8) + 1 , CHARINDEX('Logic',A2, 8) - 4 - CHARINDEX( '=',A2,8) + 1 ) 
    ELSE SUBSTRING( A2, CHARINDEX( '=',A2, 8) + 1 , 5 ) 
    END
```

Comment: thank a lot for your answer @Serkan Arslan, i still have trouble, the error message:
Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the same result, this query might work for you. It uses Try-Catch logic:

```
declare @NCELL VARCHAR(200) = 'LABEL=BDGblablabalba,CellID=24539, LogicRNCID=382'

begin try
select isnull((SUBSTRING(@NCELL, CHARINDEX('CellID', @NCELL) + 7, CHARINDEX(', Logic', @NCELL) - (CHARINDEX('CellID', @NCELL) + 7))), 'N/A') AS Result
end try
begin catch
select SUBSTRING(@NCELL, CHARINDEX('CellID', @NCELL) + 7, 200) AS Result
end catch
```